# Delay HttpWebrequest with Threading

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I use a proxy and visit some webpages with `HttpWebReuqest`. Sometimes a welcome message comes from the proxy and says I will be redirected to the desired page after 10 seconds.

This happens when I have already received the response. So the content inside:

```
   HttpWebResponse urlResponse =(HttpWebResponse ) urlRequest.GetResponse();

   Stream contentStream = urlResponse.GetResponseStream();
   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(contentStream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-9"));

   content = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

is not what I am looking for.

I tried setting allow autoredirect to true, but it didn't help, because the page is loaded without any redirect, but still waits 10 seconds.

Is there a way to fix this problem? How can I implement threading with:

```
HttpWebResponse urlResponse =(HttpWebResponse )urlRequest.GetResponse();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either disable the 10 sec wait in your proxy server or parse the HTML output to get the redirect URL, this URL could be in `HTTP meta refresh` or in some JavaScript

Comment: I want to visit the page with proxy, I already have the destination url but this is like a buffer page between me and destination on proxy-side, What i need is to get response of the page 11 seconds later url requested